# Session:get-attribute('_eXist_xmldb_user') - How to get the username as a string?

Tags: xml, rest, xquery, exist-db

I need to get the username of the current session as a string

this:

```
session:get-attribute('_eXist_xmldb_user')

returns this:

[auth] <account name="foobar" id="11"><group name="dba" id="1048575"><manager name="admin"/></group></user>
```

But I only want the username that, in this example, is:

```
foobar
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use `xmldb:get-current-user()`? I think you would have to parse the result of `session:get-attribute('_eXist_xmldb_user')` with a regex. It is not a element, so XPath does not work. I am not quite sure what the type of this value is - it is not xs:string, but it can be cast to a string.

Comment: @JensØstergaardPetersen
I didn't knew about xmldb:get-current-user(), thank you so much. Could you answer my question with that so it will be easier to find for other people?

Comment: just curious: where did you learn about getting this attribute? I can't find any references to it in the documentation.

Comment: @JensØstergaardPetersen 
I've declared the namespace session and then there was a function called session:get-attribute-names that returned the list of attributes that could be retrieved through session:get-attribute(), and i picked '_exist_xmldb_user'.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess the only difference between `session:get-attribute('org.exist.login.user')` and `xmldb:get-current-user()` is that the first returns empty, not 'guest', if the user has not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the string value of the current user in eXist-db, call `xmldb:get-current-user()`. In case the user has not logged in, this returns 'guest'.

(I know this is not an answer to your question, but it solves your problem).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
session:get-attribute('_eXist_xmldb_user')//account/@name
```

Comment: That xml structure returned by the get-attribute() function doesn't make any sense...

Comment: It is indeed bad XML. Obviously, `</user>` should be `</account>`. Its count is 1 and its type is probably just xs:anyAtomicType. It is output to the console upon an authentication event: `Authenticated by 'exist' as '[auth] <account name="guest" id="1048573"><group name="guest" id="1048574"><manager name="admin"/></group></user>'`.